# Form_validation run false in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

"","style" => "height:450px;width:350px;margin-left:10px;background-color:white;"));?>
                            Edit Property
                            ">
                            **Description:**">
                                
                                
                                    
                                
                                
                                **Department**
                            
                                >English Department
                                >Mathematics Dept.
                                >Filipino Dept.
                                >Science Dept.
                                >Social Studies Dept.
                                >MAPEH Dept.
                                >Computer Dept.
                                >Home Economics Dept.
                                >Values Dept.
                            
                                **Life Years:**">
                                        
                                        
                                            
                                        
                                        
                                **Cost:**">
                                        
                                        
                                            
                                        
                                        
                                **Officer:**">
                                        
                                        
                                            
                                        
                                        
                                **Quantity:**">
                                        
                                        
                                            
                                        
                                                           
                            
                                 "btn btn-default"));?>

```
public function edit_prop(){
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('description','Description','required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('quantity','Quantity','required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('lifeyears','Life Years','required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('cost','Cost','required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('accountable_officer','Accountable Officer','required');

        if($this->form_validation->run() == false){
            if($this->properties->update_prop() == true){
                $this->session->set_flashdata('updated', 'Updated Successfully!');
                redirect('properties_controller/view_properties');
            }
        }
        else{
            $data = array(
                    'id' => $this->input->post('id'),
                    'description' => $this->input->post('description'),
                    'accountable' => $this->input->post('accountable'),
                    'lifeyears' => $this->input->post('lifeyears'),
                    'cost' => $this->input->post('cost'),
                    'accountable_officer' => $this->input->post('accountable_officer'),
                    'quantity' => $this->input->post('quantity')
                );              
                $data['design'] = 'update_property';
                $data['title'] = 'Properties Corner!';
                $this->load->view('template_dashboard',$data);
       }
```

Comment: So what's your question?..

Comment: Tidy up your code also and what's your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Could not figure out what your after I think what you are trying to do is something like code below.

**Would recommend think about your question first next time.**

**Just Examples Only**

Also check you have set your routes and in form action use

```
$routes['controller_name'] = "controller_name/index";
$routes['controller_name/add'] = "controller_name/add";
$routes['controller_name/edit/(:any)'] = "controller_name/edit/$1";
```

Read User Guide. `http://localhost/project/something/edit/1 $this->uri->segment(what_your_id_is_in_url);`

**View Form**

```
action="<?php echo base_url('controller_name/edit' .'/'. $this->uri->segment(3));?>"
```

**Example:**

```
<?php

class Controller_name extends CI_Controller {

public function index() {

  if ($this->uri->segment(3) == TRUE) {
    $this->edit_prop();
  } else {
    $this->add_prop();
  }
}

public function add_prop() { 
}

public function edit_prop(){

$this->load->library('form_validation');

$data['design'] = 'update_property';
$data['title'] = 'Properties Corner!';

$this->form_validation->set_rules('description','Description','required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('quantity','Quantity','required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('lifeyears','Life Years','required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('cost','Cost','required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('accountable_officer','Accountable Officer','required');

if($this->form_validation->run() == false){

$this->load->view('template_dashboard', $data);

} else {

$this->load->model('model_name');

$id = $this->uri->segment(3); // Read User Guide. http://localhost/project/something/edit/1 $this->uri->segment(what_your_id_is_in_url);

$this->model_name->edit($id);

$this->session->set_flashdata('updated', 'Updated Successfully!');
redirect('properties_controller/view_properties');

}

}
```

Model

```
class Model_name extends CI_Model {

public function edit($id) {
    $data = array(
        'id' => $this->input->post('id'),
        'description' => $this->input->post('description'),
        'accountable' => $this->input->post('accountable'),
        'lifeyears' => $this->input->post('lifeyears'),
        'cost' => $this->input->post('cost'),
        'accountable_officer' => $this->input->post('accountable_officer'),
        'quantity' => $this->input->post('quantity')
    );    

    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $this->db->update('table_name', $data);      

}
}
```